# Arduino IDE can't find message header

Tags: ros, arduino, ros-lunar, rosseral-arduino, custom-message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey, I'm new to ROS and trying to have a led blink at will with my Arduino from my computer using a message, the future goal being to control several ones from my terminal. I am using ROS lunar and the rosserial_arduino package.

I wrote my publisher, subscriber and message, ran the package from a terminal to another as a test and it worked perfectly.
Then I put the subscriber code in a new Arduino sketch and adapted it. However, when I try to compile it, I get the following error:

```
/home/eric/Arduino/blink_one_ros/blink_one_ros.ino:2:30: fatal error: blink_one/Number.h: No such file or directory
 #include <blink_one/Number.h>
                              ^
```

My include being as follows:

```
#include <ros.h>
#include <blink_one/Number.h>
```

I already looked into [this answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/229511/how-to-use-custom-message-arduino-solved/) and several others, but I am afraid that it would be an error from my package so I want to be sure before re-installing ROS.

I did run the often advised:

```
rm -rf ros_lib/
rosrun rosserial_arduino make_libraries.py <my_path>
```

And indeed, I can find my message header in my ros_lib/blink_one . Yet it still does not seem to be recognized.

If anyone knows a solution or has some hints, I'd appreciate it!

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/292116/arduino-ide-can%27t-find-message-header/) by [RicHykkie](https://answers.ros.org/users/34053/richykkie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-05-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [simbha](https://answers.ros.org/users/29493/simbha/) on 2018-05-24**:
is the blink_one msg is written by use? because by default there is no such msg

**Comment by [RicHykkie](https://answers.ros.org/users/34053/richykkie/) on 2018-05-24**:
I don't quite understand the question, sorry.
I made it so that the publisher node running in my PC publishes a message into a topic that will be read by the subscriber node, which will be loaded in the Arduino. The message data is an integer, that I want to input in my terminal.

**Comment by [simbha](https://answers.ros.org/users/29493/simbha/) on 2018-05-24**:
what is the msg type of your topic? please check using `rostopic info /topic name` . I just want to know what is `<blink_one/Number.h>`. please let me know the msg type(std_msgs/Int64 or ?) of topic.

**Comment by [RicHykkie](https://answers.ros.org/users/34053/richykkie/) on 2018-05-24**:
It should be an int16 but when I type this, I get `Type: blink_one/Number`

**Comment by [simbha](https://answers.ros.org/users/29493/simbha/) on 2018-05-24**:
Then why are you including `<blink_one/Number.h`. It should be `#include std_msgs/Int16.h`

**Comment by [RicHykkie](https://answers.ros.org/users/34053/richykkie/) on 2018-05-24**:
Sorry, I slightly modified my previous answer after checking.
About the use of the include, it's because I call this function `void chatterCallback(const blink_one::Number msg) { code... }`.

**Comment by [simbha](https://answers.ros.org/users/29493/simbha/) on 2018-05-24**:
How you have created `blink_one/Number.h`. Make sure it is available in `Arduino/libraries/ros_lib/blink_one/Number.h`. refre [this link](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials)

**Comment by [RicHykkie](https://answers.ros.org/users/34053/richykkie/) on 2018-05-24**:
I created the header by first creating the `.msg` file, then adding the required lines in the CMakeLists as shown in the msg and srv tutorials and finally `catkin_make`.
Yes, the header is in the `ros_lib/blink_one` folder.

**Comment by [simbha](https://answers.ros.org/users/29493/simbha/) on 2018-05-24**:
are the examples of ros_lib are compiling successfully?

**Comment by [RicHykkie](https://answers.ros.org/users/34053/richykkie/) on 2018-05-24**:
Yes they do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You cannot compile the same source code for a linux ROS node in the arduino IDE for that platform, they are totally different environments with different libraries. Have you looked at [this rosserial tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Blink) for building a subscriber node on an arduino?

@simbha commented that you're using a custom message type for this and checking that you have built the messages correctly. There is no need for this custom message type by the way there are plenty of [standard messages](http://wiki.ros.org/std_msgs) that could serve you just as well and make your build process simpler.

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [simbha](https://answers.ros.org/users/29493/simbha/) on 2018-05-24**:
@RIcHykkie refer [this link](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_client/Tutorials/Generating%20Message%20Header%20Files) to generate msgs for Arduino

**Comment by [RicHykkie](https://answers.ros.org/users/34053/richykkie/) on 2018-05-24**:
@PeteBlackerThe3rd Yeah I used this tutorial to adapt my code for Arduino. The Rosserial Arduino Library does appear in my *Examples* so I assume this has been built properly.

**Comment by [RicHykkie](https://answers.ros.org/users/34053/richykkie/) on 2018-05-24**:
@simbha Thanks for the link, I tried running `rosrun rosserial_client make_library.py ~/sketchbook/libraries blink_one` but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Running `rosrun rosserial_arduino make_libraries.py /home/eric/sketchbook/libraries/ blink_one`creates the header but still no compiling.

**Comment by [RicHykkie](https://answers.ros.org/users/34053/richykkie/) on 2018-05-24**:
Thank you for your answers.

For now I will try using standard messages, but for later uses I would like to be able to create my own, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello there,
i know that post is a little bit old. But i had the same problem and found a workaround. My setup is a raspberry which runs ubuntu. I used the ros distribution. Arduino was installed with the install package from the website, not from the ubuntu repository. I found the the libraries for the arduino compilation are stored in the /usr/share/arduino/libraries folder.

- user : ubuntu
- package where the msg is defined : hw_arduino_package
- message in the msg folder :  stepperAction.msg

So as workaround i firsat generate the libraries with the python script into a temp folder :

```
rosrun rosserial_arduino make_libraries.py /home/ubuntu/ardtemp hw_arduino_package
```

Than i have to copy the generated package library to the arduino library folder.

```
sudo cp -R /home/ubuntu/ardtemp/ros_lib/hw_arduino_package /usr/share/arduino/libraries/
```

After that it can be included in the arduino package source with

```
#include <hw_arduino_package/stepperAction.h>
```

I know that is not the best practise, but it works for me. Maybe this would help someone.

---

Originally posted by [oligor77](https://answers.ros.org/users/40260/oligor77/) with karma: 11 on 2019-04-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [root_locus](https://answers.ros.org/users/39121/root_locus/) on 2019-09-01**:
Thank you!! :D